# Security Review of Proposed System -- How to send images securely

Tags: audit

I have a mobile application that needs to be able to send images securely to other mobile phone(s).  I've attempted to research this out and I have an idea in my mind how it could work, but I want to pass it by some of you to make sure.

**Definitions:**

- Receiving Phone -- The phone that will receive pictures.  There could be multiples of these.
- Sending Phone -- The phone that will send pictures.  There could be multiples of these.
- Account -- Grouping of receiving phones and sending phones.

**Steps:**

1. One or more receiving phones is registered to the account.  Each of them create a 2048 bit RSA keypair using the Android Keystore or the iOS keychain.  The public key is sent to the backend where it is saved.  My understanding (and from experimentation) is that the private key CANNOT be extracted from the Android Keystore/iOS Keychain.*
2. Before sending a picture, a sending phone downloads ALL of the public keys for the receiving phones.  It then generates a 256 AES key (probably using CBC?) which it uses to encrypt the photo.  That key is then encrypted using the public RSA key**s** downloaded from the backend server.  The encrypted image, the encrypted AES keys, and other information (IV?--should that be encrypted too?) is sent to the backend server where it is save.
3. The receiving phones download the images from the backend server, decrypt the AES key using their private key from their keystore/keychain, then decrypt the images using the AES key.
4. All images are deleted from the backend server after 14 days.

*I understand that if a phone uninstalls the app the KeyPair is lost and that IS OKAY.

*Please Note:  The backend server will save the encrypted images on an encrypted volume, and all communicate will be done through https.  You can assume that access to the backend server will require authorization, and is (attempted) to be controlled.  While that can have security implications itself, I want to focus this post more on the images (if that works?).  If you need more details about the system then let me know.*

**Questions:**

1. How secure does this seem?  What have I missed?  What else should I consider?  *(I'm no security expert)*
2. In the case that someone DOES hack into my backend, and they do get access to the encrypted images, how secure are the photos then?  *(My goal is to make it so that "hacker" would have to hack the users phone too in order to decrypt the pictures).*
3. Is it a problem that I'll have the same AES key encrypted with potentially multiple RSA public keys?

Comment: What you propose is very similar to PGP. Maybe you just use PGP instead?

Comment: Is your goal to implement E2EE?  If not, just use TLS.  Don't reinvent the wheel.  Also, you havent talked about authenticating your ciphertext at all.  CBC mode means no authentication.  You should use an HMAC.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? There are existing services to do this. [Telegram](https://telegram.org/) for example.

Comment: While the functionality I described is duplicated using other apps, the app itself is different.  @steffen-ullrich I hadnt looked into PGP.  I'll jump in and see if I can find Android and iOS libraries for it.

Comment: @luke-park its vital to my users that even I (or any engineer) can't decrypt the images.  Thats what led me down this path.  I'll look into HMAC.  What advantages does it give me over CBC (aside from not needing an IV)?

Comment: It isn't a replacement for CBC mode. If you need to ask a question like that you definitely should not be implementing this yourself.  Hire someone who knows what they are doing.

Comment: @LukePark You'd think a question and answer forum would be more friendly of people lacking knowledge and trying to get more of it.  Thank you for asking me more questions.  I'll look into what you suggested.

Comment: I'm not trying to be unfriendly, but learning something by implementing it in production, **especially** cryptography, is a really poor idea. I'm trying to help your project. Sorry if that came across rude.  People don't take things as seriously if you fill your comments with smiley faces.